# Windows 7 dual NIC. Connections on NIC1 drop when other PC on NIC2 wakes up

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

I have a PC which has one onboard Realtek NIC, and a PCIe Intel NIC. The Realtek NIC (NIC1) is the default Gateway to the Internet. On the Intel NIC (NIC2) there's a backup server connected directly via a single cable, the two share a common subnet which no other device is part of. When the backup server wakes up, then all connections on NIC1 drop. They can reconnect immediately, but all TCP connections that are active at the moment of the transition do drop.

The same occurs when the backup server goes to sleep.

When the backup server is online, the Media State listed as Enabled 1Gbps, when it is sleeping, the Media State is listed as Enabled 10Mbps, because WOL is enabled on the backup server.

Is it normal that NIC1 is affected by this?

Comment: Nope. Not normal.  Sanity check, Both are on different subnets?

Comment: @Hennes Yes, very definitely different subnets. Could this be a Firewall issue? I'm not using the built-in one. Like maybe the Firewall resets itself when it sees that something NIC-related changed? Or the VirtualBox Bridged Network driver?

Comment: Make sure there's no default gateway or default route configured on the link to the backup server.